# como hago para restringir el login a usuarios logueados - Django(python)

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Tengo algo así, no manejo algo personalizado. Existe alguna forma de restringir la vista de login, para que solo se les muestre a los usuarios no logueados?

Comment: En este caso deberia personalizar las vistas de django.contrib.auth.urls tu mismo y no incluir las directamente.

Comment: Una vez que las tengas ya personalizadas, si estas usando funciones como vistas usas el decorador django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test, y si usas vistas genericas usarias la clase django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin

Comment: Una url donde puedes encontrar un poco más de documentación: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test

Comment: Intetare ponerte un ejemplo pero me llevara algo de tiempo, para mientras puedes usar el link de arriba. Espero te sirva para mientras.